# Is there 'strings' command for utf-8?

Tags: string, bash, utf-8

The linux command `strings` looks for ASCII strings in a binary file.
Are there any command line tools to show UTF-8 strings in a binary file?

Comment: no, there is not.

Comment: related: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27551 | https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9984 Here's one implementation: https://github.com/getreu/stringsext "stringsext is a Unicode enhancement of the GNU strings tool with additional functionalities: stringsext recognizes Cyrillic, Arabic, CJKV characters and other scripts in all supported multi-byte-encodings"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `strings` command supports the `--encoding` option. Check the [man page](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strings.html).

But however, I failed to extract UTF-8 strings using any possible option value. Currently searching their mailing list. will update this if I find more help

Comment: UTF-8 characters are variable byte width, which won't work with the fixed width pattern matching nature of `strings`.

Comment: On my Debian 9, `strings -e S` works with UTF-8. `strings` version: `2.28`, `LANG`=`de_CH.UTF-8`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Thanks for the comment! I'll test it later and update the answer if I can reproduce it

Comment: ["S = single-8-bit-byte characters"](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/strings.html), do you have any reference about why that option works for UTF-8? Piping through `grep -q -n -axv'.*'` still show some garbage, also through ` iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c`.

Comment: @PabloA I think you are right, S will only work for those utf-8 characters which are encoded in one byte, which is more than ascii but far from working. I've removed that

Comment: @hek2mgl: Erm... the characters encoded in one byte of UTF-8 are *exactly* those of ASCII-7 (0x00..0x7f).

Comment: @DevSolar Ascii has only 127 chars

Comment: @hek2mgl: Indeed. The 127 chars that require only 7 bits to encode. Coincidentially, the 127 chars that UTF-8 encodes with one byte, because the most significant bit set is UTF-8's way to tell if any given byte is part of a multibyte sequence.

Comment: Ascii is using unsigned char -> 127 characters, utf is using a signed char for the first byte: 255 characters. For many languages, like European languages, this makes the utf-8 part of it (without special chars of course). Like the German Ä, it is encoded in the non ascii portion of the first byte

Comment: Can't make much sense of that last comment. The characters which UTF-8 encodes in one byte are code points U+0000 through U+007F. These are identical with the same range (0x00 through 0x7f) of ASCII-7, which incidentially is **all** of ASCII-7. For anything beyond that, like "Ä", UTF-8 uses two bytes or more (whereas ISO/IEC 8859 / "extended ASCII" uses the range of 0x80..0xff to encode additional characters in a collection of one-byte encodings). "UTF-8 characters which are encoded in one byte, which is more than ASCII" do not exist.

Comment: Also, neither ASCII nor UTF-8 make any statement about the signed-ness of their characters. Indeed, the C/C++ standards go to some length enabling both ways to encode `char`.